# Scala catch thrown errors by a sequence of futures

Tags: scala, sequence, future, recover

Is it possible to asynchronously catch all errors given a list of futures?

I was thinking of something like:

```
Future { throw Exception } zip Future { throw Exception } recover ...
```

But I only receive a Throwable in the recover part. Any idea?

Comment: Can you add a recover to both `Future`'s before zipping them?

Comment: I'm showing a simplified example. That's what I actually did, but the thing is that I want to combine the exceptions thrown by all the futures that have failed.

Answer (score 3):

`zip`'s [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.concurrent.Future) clearly say it prefers errors from `this` over those from `that` (my emphasis):

> `def zip[U](that: Future[U]): Future[(T, U)]` Zips the values of `this`
>   and `that` future, and creates a new future holding the tuple of their
>   results.
>
> If `this` future fails, the resulting future is failed with the
>   throwable stored in `this`. ***Otherwise***, if `that` future fails, the
>   resulting future is failed with the throwable stored in `that`.

You could implement your own function to combine two futures into `Future[(Try[T], Try[U])]`, like:

```
def zipToTry[T,U](a: Future[T], b: Future[U])
                 (implicit executor: ExecutionContext)
    : Future[(Try[T], Try[U])] = {

  val t: Try[T] = a.map { Success(_) }.recover { Failure(_) }
  val u: Try[U] = b.map { Success(_) }.recover { Failure(_) }
  t.zip(u)
}
```

(i haven't tested this, but you get the idea)